# How can I apply date formatting to Ghost's post.published_at property?

Tags: date, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

How can I format `post.published_at` in Ghost?

By default this returns the string:

> Mon Nov 04 2013 13:29:46 GMT+0100 (CET)

Using `format` returns the same string.

```
{{ post.published_at format='dddd, MMMM Do YYYY' }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `post.published_at` is a javascript DateTime, then you'll need to invoke a helper to format it.

It looks like the standard helper for this in Ghost is `{{date}}`, so try `{{date post.published_at}}`.

Here's a link to the Ghost helpers script file, since this doesn't seem to be published in documentation anywhere: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/helpers/index.js

Comment: Sure thing.  You might have noticed this also, but it looks like that helper can take the post itself and will detect .published_at.  Plus, you can then append the format as a parameter.  So {{date post format='blah'}} should also do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `{{date}}` helper, you can then pass in any format supported by the [moment](http://momentjs.com/) javascript date library.

This helper, and all the others, are documented at http://docs.ghost.org/themes